# mysql query planning to obtain travel

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i had an exercise that i don't know how to resolve it.
Here a table PLANNING where there is the planning of workers in a month :

```
IDPERSONNE  DATE    IDPLACE HEURE_DEBUT HEURE_FIN
1        26/09/2017   1       08:00       08:45
1        26/09/2017   1       09:00       10:00
1        26/09/2017   2       10:00       12:00
1        26/09/2017   1       13:00       15:00
1        26/09/2017   2       15:00       17:00
1        26/09/2017   1       17:00       18:00
2        02/09/2017   3       09:00       10:00
2        02/09/2017   3       10:00       12:00
2        02/09/2017   4       13:00       18:00
2        03/09/2017   3       09:00       10:00
2        03/09/2017   3       10:00       12:00
2        03/09/2017   4       13:00       18:00
```

I want to know the different travel of workers in a day with the end time he was in a place and the begin time he begin in another place. Like this :

```
IDPERSONNE  DATE    IDPLACE1    HEURE_FIN_PLACE1    IDPLACE2    HEURE_DEBUT_PLACE2
1       26/09/2017     1            10:00              2            10:00
1       26/09/2017     2            12:00              1            13:00
1       26/09/2017     1            15:00              2            15:00
1       26/09/2017     2            17:00              1            17:00
2       02/09/2017     3            12:00              4            13:00
2       03/09/2017     3            12:00              4            13:00
```

I've tried something like this :

```
SELECT p1.IDPERSONNE, p1.DATE, p1.IDPLACE, max(p1.HEURE_FIN), p2.IDPLACE,     min(p2.HEURE_DEBUT)
FROM PLANNING p1
INNER JOIN PLANNING p2 on p1.IDPERSONNE=p2.IDPERSONNE and p1.DATE=p2.DATE and p1.HEURE_DEBUT < p2.HEURE_DEBUT
WHERE p1.IDPLACE <> p2.IDPLACE
GROUP BY p1.IDPERSONNE, p1.DATE
```

but if a person make lot of travels in a day between two places, i have only 2 travels in my results.

Please help me!

Thanks in advance